# Debugging node app in WebStorm when run from gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, webstorm

I am using `webstorm 10.0.2` and have used the `bangular` `yeoman` template to generate a project. I can run the gulp commands via the gulp window, and I can set a breakpoint in the `gulpfile.js` and it will hit it, but I can't seem to get it to hit a breakpoint in my `server.js`

It looks to me like the gulp file is launching another instance of `node` and thus when you do "debug" from webstorm you are just debugging the gulp.

I also tried with another project using `yo hottowel` but get the same thing - I am unable to debug the actual application through webstorm.

Can anybody tell me how to configure webstorm so that I can debug the actual server side node code but still use the gulp build tool?

Comment: Have the same problem. @gremwell did you find a solution?

Comment: I posted it as an answer (basically no solution)

Answer (score 1):

I contacted JetBrains support back in May 2015 and their response was:

> It seems this cannot be done quickly. In short, the problem is that serve-dev task starts new process (nodemon) that takes app.js
>   There is no workaround how to debug such spawned processes right now. We would really appreciate if you'll submit a feature request about it in our YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB
>   The only way you can try to avoid it - try to create a separate task that will run app.js directly without nodemon process and debug this task instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best option is to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-node-inspector